# How to get clear legend on ggplot2 while mixing bar charts and points?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I've been struggling for hours with my problem. I'm comparing two resolution methods of a bi-objective problem. I want to compare them and represent the deviation of both objective function, then add points to represent the savings in dollars which are calculated a posteriori (just for the information).

I can get "easily" the graph I want, but I'm really struggling with the legend. I've tried with some success two approaches to get my final plot (I'm definitely a beginner in R so my code may be far from well thought)

```
`library(easyGgplot2)
library(reshape2)

instances <-c("a","b","c","d","e")
dev1 <- c(20,41,-5, 10,14)
dev2 <- c(0,-12,23,-14,0)
sav <- c(0.55,1.04,-0.8,1.1,-0.03)

df <- data.frame(instances, dev1, dev2, sav)
names(df)<-c("Instances", "Deviation1", "Deviation2", "Savings")

#1st approach
g1 <- ggplot2.barplot(df, xName = "Instances", yName = 'Deviation1', ytitle = "Variations in units of time")+geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="steelblue") 
g2 <- g1 + geom_bar(aes(df[,"Instances"], df[,'Deviation2']),stat="identity", fill = "red")

map<-aes(df[,"Instances"], df[,'Savings']*10)

g3 <- g2+ geom_point(map)+geom_text(map, vjust =-0.5,label = round( c(df[,'Savings']),1))
g4 <- g3 + scale_y_continuous("Variation in time units", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 0.10, name = "Savings in %"))
g4


#2nd approach
x <- as.data.frame(list(variable=unlist(instances), 
                         deva =unlist(dev1),  devb = unlist(dev2)))
x
dat = melt(x, id.var="variable", variable.name="type")
dat$type = factor(as.character(dat$type), 
                  levels=c("deva", "devb"))
colorsPerso = c(deva="steelblue", devb="red")
plot_1 = ggplot(dat, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=type)) +
  geom_bar(position="stack",stat="identity") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=colorsPerso)

map2<-aes(c(df[,"Instances"],df[,"Instances"]), c(df[,'Savings']*10,df[,'Savings']*10))
plot_2 <- plot_1 + geom_point(map2)+geom_text(map2, vjust =-0.5,label = round( c(df[,'Savings']*10,df[,'Savings']*10),1))
plot_3 <- plot_2 + scale_y_continuous("Variation in time units", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . * 0.10, name = "Savings in %"))
plot_3
`
```

I don't know how to get a proper legend for the first legend, nor ou to get the dots out of the squares of the second legend. (But the plots I get are exactly what I'm looking for, with two different scales on the left and right hand side depending if we're dealing with deviation or savings).

Edit : here is what I get with both approaches

[Plot1, first approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0KuJ.png)

[Plot2, second approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRDEq.png)

I do thank you for your help.

Have a good day

Alexis

Comment: Where is `easyGgplot2` coming from? This does not seem to be an R CRAN package. Is that where `ggplot2.barplot` comes from?

Comment: When I first wanted to use ggplot2, I found a piece of code including

install_github("easyGgplot2", "kassambara")
library(easyGgplot2)

And it worked (seems to work at least) perfectly as if it was ggplot2

Comment: Can you post images of the plots you get with your current code? `easyGgplot2` is not a widely used package, so I would recommend against  using it. From the code you posted, I don't see that it saves much, and it may encourage misuse of ggplot2. Your line starting with `map<-aes(` is definitely wrong, you should not feed data into the `aes()` function.

Comment: I'm not really willing to use easyGgplot2, no problem with using the standard one, but I think they are working the same way (mith aesthetic mapping etc...). I've updated my original post.